# SFML error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, sfml, symbols

I just started a new C++ SFML project, I have an old one that works.
I linked sfml like the tutorial said, so I think that isn't the problem. I even recreated the project and linked everything again...

Now this is the only code I have:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"

#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

// run the program as long as the window is open
while (window.isOpen())
{
    // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        // "close requested" event: we close the window
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

I am getting these errors:

```
NHTV Assignment.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::Window::close(void)" (__imp_?close@Window@sf@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main
```

and then a couple more like these...

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Thanks...

Comment: Did you add a reference for the SFML library to your project?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I searched alot on the internet, couldn't find a fix for me so I thought I'd open a question myself...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think so yes, you mean in the project settings > linker > general section?

Comment: @JesperKlippel If you did so, there could be still an issue with compatibility regarding  32/64 bit code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Okay... Do you mean SFML 32/64 bit version? What can I do to resolve that?

Comment: @JesperKlippel Study the linked post from above.